# React Navigation drawer doesn't display the title of the current page

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I created 2 pages namely Home and Profile and added these two pages to createDrawerNavigation. And then added this drawer navigation to a stack navigator. Now when I try to display the title on the header of the current page. I'm unable to do it.

Here is my code.

Tried DefaultNavigationOptions and got the props value of navigator but doesn't work that way.

```
const MenuStack = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    HomePage: {
      screen: Home
    },
    ProfilePage: {
      screen: Profile
    }
  },
  {
    drawerWidth: Math.round(Dimensions.get("window").width) * 0.75,
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: theme.colors.accent
    }
  }
);

const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    MenuStack: {
      screen: MenuStack
    }
  },
  {
    defaultNavigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => {
      return {
        headerLeft: (
          <Icon
            style={{ paddingLeft: 10 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
            name="bars"
            size={30}
          />
        ),
        headerRight: (
          <Icon
            style={{ paddingRight: 10 }}
            onPress={() => navigation.toggleDrawer()}
            name="search"
            size={30}
          />
        ),
        headerTitle: navigation.state.routeName,
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: theme.colors.accent
        }
      };
    }
  }
);


export const createRootNavigator = (signedIn = false) => {
  return createAppContainer(
    createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        SignedIn: {
          screen: AppStack
        },
        SignedOut: {
          screen: WelcomeStack
        },
        SignInAndOut: {
          screen: AuthStack
        }
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: signedIn ? "SignedIn" : "SignedOut"
      }
    )
  );
};
```

[image]

I added a headerTitle property in the createStackNavigator but I tell the "menustack" as the title for every page.
Expected the title of the page on the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 options:

#### 1. Render your own header component in each screen

You can render a header inside your screens, either a custom one or one from a component library such as [react native paper](https://reactnativepaper.com).

```js
function Home() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <MyCustomHeader title="Home" />
      {{ /* screen content */ }}
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

#### 2. Create a stack navigator for each screen that needs to have header

```js
const MenuStack = createDrawerNavigator({
  HomePage: {
    screen: createStackNavigator({ Home })
  },
  ProfilePage: {
    screen: createStackNavigator({ Profile })
  }
});
```

Keep in mind that while this requires less code, it's also less performant.